# $_GET parameter not coming through in php

Tags: php, wordpress, audio

I'm trying to debug a problem with a wordpress plugin.

It creates some html like this:

```
 <audio src="http://mydomain.com/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/the-stiz-audio-for-woocommerce/server/preview.mp3?nonce=e38553d840&audio=4mgvi4h3Jg5qD_Vj5Qj5Kp9V3WxcfxSqhZ71zoEfqGPM3xQL-KqT7fsCoywEk3_VmJSZpMnCa5FNYB_H_50Uwuvy6G8iDgNbMP2ezlV3moj8T0mUkoj7R5tcegYlyRAu3cNTZvTkza4A0P7_g2AhhvQ60FwFAvGZ9jjy9iPJIdU" 
  class="wcjd-audio-individual" type="audio/mpeg">
 </audio>
```

preview.mp3 is actually a php script.

The 'nonce' param makes it into the script ok, but 'audio' is empty, although it is set. It must be getting stripped off for some reason but I don't know why.

EDIT:

Thanks for the replies so far...

I didn't include the php code originally because it's very simple, but I should have:

```
/**
 * @file Instantiate a WCJDServerAudio instance and allow it handle the request.
 */

define('WCJD_ROOT', realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../'));
include_once WCJD_ROOT.'/../../../wp-config.php';
include_once WCJD_ROOT.'/include.php';

$fp = fopen("../../log.txt", "w");
fwrite($fp, "nonce: ".$_GET['nonce']."\n");
fwrite($fp, "audio: ".$_GET['audio']);
fclose($fp);
// The code above results in a file with
// nonce: a90c436753
// audio:

$server = new WCJDServeAudio($_GET);

// Determine whether this is a valid request
if ($server->validRequest()) {
    $server->output();
    die();
} else {
    header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden');
    include WCJD_ROOT.'/views/error/403.php';
}
```

If I simply run this script in a browser it's able to see the 'audio' param, but when it runs as a script from inside the 'audio' tag, the audio param is stripped.

I added some code before the '$server =' part that wrote the contents of $_GET to a log file so I could see in the latter case - and only 'nonce' is set.

The .htaccess is indeed set to make sure the .mp3 extension gets treated as a .php in that directory.

The way it behaves makes me think there is some kind of size limit or magic-quotes issue causing it to drop the audio param. But I have no idea.

Comment: Did you actually set your .htaccess config to parse .mp3 extensions? Also, please show your preview.mp3 php script...

Comment: It would be helpful to see the PHP that is supposed to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like its working as it should. We can't help you unless you post the PHP code.

This works on my localhost pretty well.

```
<?php
echo $_GET['nonce'];
echo "<br>";
echo $_GET['audio'];
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for checking, it works for me in the browser but not when called from inside the audio tag.